# How do I stream a file from NodeJS to Amazon S3, using Knox?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, streaming, knox-amazon-s3-client

I'm very new to streams in NodeJS - basically clueless about them - and I'm trying to get the KnoxJS client for Amazon S3 to stream a file from an HTTP GET.

The sample code on the Knox github page shows this:

```
http.get('http://google.com/doodle.png', function(res){
  var headers = {
      'Content-Length': res.headers['content-length']
    , 'Content-Type': res.headers['content-type']
  };
  client.putStream(res, '/doodle.png', headers, function(err, res){
    // check `err`, then do `res.pipe(..)` or `res.resume()` or whatever.
  });
});
```

But this is very clearly incomplete... it really doesn't do much of anything other than open the `http.get` and `putStream` for S3.

So where do I go from here? Can someone help me complete this code so that I can stream a file from an HTTP GET to my bucket on S3?

Comment: Agree, this is such a common request, it would be helpful to put some docs around this task. Believe you do need to know the file size up front (as indicated above) for streaming to work - this puts some restrictions on suitability. @Derick Bailey if you got this working - can you post your solution - will save others time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you're inside this callback:

```
//check `err`, then do `res.pipe(..)` or `res.resume()` or whatever
```

The response from google has been streamed to S3 already (that's what knox's `putStream` does for you), and `err, res` are S3's response, so you don't have to anything else here other than check error and something like `console.log("Upload done")` if this is a command line snippet. Their docs here are saying if this entire snippet was within the context of an HTTP req/res interaction between say a browser and a node.js web app, then you could do decide you wanted to pipe the image back to the browser as well, you could do that (at least in theory). I think the docs are a bit confusing about that, but that's my interpretation.

Comment: this doesn't seem right to me. in my "real" code, I'm streaming a few hundred megs of files, and it takes less than 2 seconds to finish. it can't be right that my computer, with it's slow internet that takes a minute or two to upload 30 megs, would be instantly done and available by the time this code is called. clearly i'm doing something wrong, or the streaming isn't working like this.

Comment: Yeah that sounds like you think your code is "finished" when the uploads have all been started and aren't waiting for them all to complete. Hard to provide guidance based on theoretical snippets. Can you extract a working .js command line program?

Comment: how do i wait for them to complete? the code posted above is what i'm starting with, and i have no idea where to go from there.

Comment: So when you want to do a batch of stuff, you bump into the node async flow control problem. You can use something like `async.parallel` which will do them all in parallel and let you know when they are all done or the equivalent in a promise library like Q or whatever. `async.eachLimit` is also great for allowing N to upload at the same time.

Comment: let's start with one file, then. does the above code actually completely stream 1 file?

Comment: Yes, when the `client.putStream` callback function executes, both the google download and the S3 upload are complete. They could have succeeded or failed, but they are done at that point in time.

Comment: looks like this was correct in the end. my original HTTP GET request had a redirect. used the "follow-redirects" npm module to make that work, and it's streaming my files correctly now.